# Where to put entity classes in three layer architecture?

Tags: jpa, n-tier-architecture

I'm required to built an application with three layer architecture. If I were to access the database in simple SQL queries, I could put domain classes in business layer and SQL queries in data layer. 
Since I intend to use JPA to access the database, to which layer should I put the entity classes? Are entity classes, a combination of both layers? If they can be included in one layer, how can I map the to the other layer?

Comment: Entity classes are usually not part of any layer: they're used by all the layers of the app: data access which persists/retrieves them, business layer which uses them, and presentation which displays them.

Comment: @JBNizet Does that mean business logic of domain classes have to be separated? Wouldn't that be considered an anti pattern? [Anemic_domain_model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model)

Comment: Just because they're used everywhere doesn't mean they can't contain logic. But the logic should generally be limited to the entity state. Entities are not supposed to access services or DAOs.